# Import moduleName on python file gives ModuleNotFound when running docker-compose on flask app

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to dockerize my flask app, and I tried to create an image as simplified as possible in order not to mess everything up.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9.1

ADD . /docker_endurance

WORKDIR /docker_endurance

RUN pip3 freeze >> requirements.txt && \
    pip3 install canopen
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: python main.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/docker_endurance
```

And my `main.py` file looks like that:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import request 
from flask import render_template
import canopen
from canopen import node
from classEndurance import Drive
from datetime import datetime
import os
from canopen.profiles.p402 import BaseNode402
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 down")
os.system("sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000")
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 up")

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hey"
(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

And of course my `requirements.txt`:

```
canopen==1.2.1
Flask==0.10.1
```

So when I tried to remove the `import canopen` from my `main.py` and run the following command line: `sudo docker-compose up`, it was working well but I need to `import canopen`.

But when I do it I have the following error:

```
309d50207174_docker_endurance_app_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
309d50207174_docker_endurance_app_1 |   File "/docker_endurance/main.py", line 4, in <module>
309d50207174_docker_endurance_app_1 |     import canopen
309d50207174_docker_endurance_app_1 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'canopen'
309d50207174_docker_endurance_app_1 exited with code 1
```

And I don't understand why as I am putting canopen in my `requirements.txt`, and in my `Dockerfile`.

I don't understand what is going wrong!

Comment: Overwriting the `requirements.txt` in the Dockerfile seems a little odd, but it also looks like you don't actually `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`.  Does adding that line in help?

Comment: The original `requirements.txt` file is overwritten by the last command in `Dockerfile` which I believe causes the issue. It doesn't contain any extra packages except ones installed by default. check it and share the observation, please ;)